# undefined local variable or method `clientid' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am new to factory_girl gem. My Ruby gem have static clientid, session & host.

My Factory code is like

```
FactoryGirl.define  do
 factory :session do |f|
        f.clientid "clientid string"
        f.secret " secret string"
        f.host "host string"
    end
end
```

My Spec code is like

```
describe '#new' do
    it 'works' do
      result = FactoryGirl.build(clientid, secret, host)
      expect(result).not_to be_nil
    end
end
```

My spec_helper file is

```
require 'rspec'
require 'factory_girl'
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
require 'mydemogem'
```

I am trying to create one factory for that. But it gives me following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `clientid' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spec has

```
result = FactoryGirl.build(clientid, secret, host)
```

but you aren't defining `clientid`, `secret`, and `host`. You can't access variables that aren't defined

Comment: I have define that in factory.rb...Am i still missing something let me know..Thanks FactoryGirl.define  do
 factory :session do |f|
        f.clientid "clientid string"
        f.secret " secret string"
        f.host "host string"
    end
end

Comment: You have defined defaults for those attributes in factory.rb, but you haven't defined the local variables that you are trying to use here. You should be able to just call `build` without any arguments in this case

Answer (score 1):

Here is some explanation:

You have defined

```
factory :session
```

File, containing this factory usually called **sessions_factory.rb**, so it is being used to produce **sessions**. You can build one with:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:session)
```

which will call:

```
Session.new(clientid: 'clientid string', secret: 'secret string', host: 'host string')
```

You can also modify some of the attributes like this:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:session, clientid: 'other id string')
```

now, the object returned will be equal to:

```
Session.new(clientid: 'other id string', secret: 'secret string', host: 'host string')
```

This is how you work with objects factory.